# Enumset wrapper for AbstractActions

Tags: java, wrapper, abstraction, enumset

I'd like to load a series of Swing Actions into a container at runtime and access them by a constant name as is possible with an Enum. The purpose of this would be to both restrict the Actions possible and also improve readability.

Initially, I was considering a sort of dynamic enum (see http://blog.xebia.com/2009/04/02/dynamic-enums-in-java/) but as Java Drinker points out below this is unnecessary since the actions remain unchanged.

Ideally, what I'd like to do is a sort of wrapper that contains `AbstractAction` instances which could be enabled/disabled and be able to refer to each action through a symbolic name.

Edit: Question has been reformulated.

Comment: But isn't the set of possible actions limited? Atleast for any particular verion of the application? Could you not have the standard static enum, with ALL the possible actions, and at runtime you have a subset of allowed actions (EnumSet in java). Then you can check against this to see if you can or not.I suppose I don't know the full breadth of your problem though...

Comment: What exactly are your "Swing Actions"? Menu Items, etc. that are faced to the User?

Comment: @Java Drinker: Yes, the set of Actions is static in nature. What would be ideal is for the Enum to act as a wrapper for Action instances, to give each Action a symbolic name and to have them loaded or enabled according to a given user. What I want to do is probably unnecessary and I will settle for a solution using an Enumset. I will reformulate my question with this in mind.

Comment: @jwatcher: They are `AbstractActions` (javax.swing.AbstractAction) which can be plugged into many Swing components. For example, an AbstractAction can be added directly to a `JMenu` if properly initialized. In the application they represent the possible actions a user can carry out (CRUD and other application-specific operations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public enum Actions {
    COPY( new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //do something
        }
    }),
    PASTE( new PasteAction() );

    public final AbstractAction action;
    private Actions(AbstractAction action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

}

//...
Actions.COPY.action...;
```

And then as others have said, use the enum in conjunction with an EnumSet or EnumMap.  Personally, I don't see a huge value in it over just having a few named fields without an enum.

I think what you really want is some kind of Action registry like this:

```
public class ActionsManager {
    private final Map<String, Action> actions;
    private final Map<User, Set<String>> enabledActions;
    public Action get(String id);
    public void register(String id, Action action);
    public void deregister(String id);
    public boolean isEnabled(User user, Action action);
}
```

Implementation left as an exercise.

Comment: From what I understand from the question, I agree with this. If you're already dealing with Action objects, enums are redundant.The ActionsManager suggested by Mark would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Mark! An action registry is a great idea. I'll see what's possible and post back here at a later date :)